# Magento 1.9 observer check if customer has at least order with complete status

Tags: magento-1.9, observer-pattern

i want to use observer to check if customer has at least one order complete to change order status to processing ( so when customer press on place order then make check if has any order complete then change status from pending to processing )
this is my code but this edit status to previous order not existing order

class ChangeOrder_Observerstatus_Model_Observer {

```
public function autoOrderevent(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{


     $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

     $orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();

     $custAdmin = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer(); 
     $custAdminId = $custAdmin->getId();

         $order_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
           ->addFieldToSelect('*')
           ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $custAdminId)
           ;

            foreach($order_collection as $order)
            {
            if ($order->getState() == "complete") {

            $Is_Complet = true;

       }

            }
             if($Is_Complet)
       {
                   if(!Mage::registry('prevent_observer')):
                     Mage::register('prevent_observer',true);
                     $orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
                     $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
                     $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true, 'Payment Complete.');
                     $order->save();
               endif;

       }
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

Use event "sales_order_place_after". Compared to other checkout events it fires in any case when order has been placed.

Your described logic has to be implemented in observers method body.

Comment: this is my code but this edit on last order not existing order

Comment: How to get a customer count of order. eg. if a customer tries to place 2nd order event observer shown second order on before place an order, i need to give a discount if the customer place 2nd order.

Comment: @Gem Do you want to show your customer the potential discount in checkout review page or just apply it afterwards? In any case you should post this as a separate question. Let me know and i'll be happy to answer.

Comment: My account unexpected error, i can't post any new post, shall i post on Magento community or Reddit?